# Custom class recognized on iOS 8.1 simulator but not on iOS 7.1 simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, ios-simulator, unrecognized-selector

I've defined a custom class named SearchView which has a method named 'setup'.

```
// SearchView.h
@interface SearchView:UIView
- (void)setup;
@end
```

I've added it to a MainViewController in the InterfaceBuilder as a subview and set it's custom class field in the identity inspector as SearchView class. I've connected this to MainViewController:

```
// MainViewController.h
@interface MainViewController:UIViewController
@end

// MainViewController.m
#import "SearchView.h"

@interface MainViewController()
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet SearchView * searchView;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)ViewDidLoad
{
   [self.searchView setup];
}
```

This app is universal so I have 2 Storyboards. When I run this on iPad simulator, it runs well for all iOS versions. But when I run this on iPhone simulator, it runs perfect for iOS 8.1 but on 7.1 I get an error which doesn't crash the app.

```
-[UIView setup]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78882660
```

I tried to move it to ViewDidAppear - no change.
I logged this ivar's class

```
- (void)ViewDidLoad
{
   NSLog(@"searchClass class: %@",NSStringFromClass([self.searchView class]));
   [self.searchView setup];
}
```

and it appears that when run on sim' 7.1 it logs

```
self.searchView: <UIView: 0x7916f540; frame = (50 0; 234 50); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7916e360>>
```

but on 8.1 sim' I get

```
self.searchView: <SearchView: 0x79e35170; frame = (50 0; 234 50); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 4444; layer = <CALayer: 0x79e349b0>>
```

I've try to tag the view and then call it with:

```
self.searchView = (SearchView*)[self.view viewWithTag:4444];
```

but the error remains.

Also, -ObjC is already added to other linker flags.

What could be the source of this error? why is this view gets cast as UIView only for this particular simulator? 
I don't have any available iOS 7 iPhone device to test it.

Comment: You said you add it in InterfaceBuilder, but why the property don't have IBOutlet?

Comment: Didn't copy it correctly, I've edited it.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but "cast" has nothing to do with the problem.  Your log lines demonstrate that it really is a different kind of view object in those two cases.  What is the parent class of `OPSearchView` (and how is that different from `SearchView`)?

Comment: It's a typo, I tried to simplify the given code for easier reading and forgot to drop the OP off the OPSearchView. Consider this as a SearchView, I apologize. Edited.

Comment: I have no idea, also. Maybe you had hide something important.

Comment: I'd be most suspicious of storyboard differences.  Does the missing "tag = 4444;" give any clues?  Should I assume that's being assigned in the storyboards...both of them?

Comment: Both hold the same tag number

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, it looks like you've connected your searchView outlet to a UIView object rather than to a SearchView object.

Comment: If this was the case then it wouldn't work on iOS 8.1 simulator too but it does. I just can't see why it doesn't work on 7.1 simulator.

Comment: Please provide a link to a sample project showing your problem or a screenshot from IB contradicting my hunch.